# No matching login attempt found with Meteor accounts oauth

Tags: meteor, oauth, meteor-accounts

I am getting "No matching login attempt found" after a successful OAuth handshake with Twitter. The accounts-ui button briefly indicates that a user is signed in, and then it immediately returns to the "Sign in with Twitter" state. There is a user document created in the database, but it does not contain any helpful fields.

Answer (score 1):

The silent issue here was that I had previously attached a schema to the `Meteor.users` collection using `aldeed:simple-schema`. Once I removed this schema, everything worked like a charm. I am unclear why a validation error did not surface, but I'm already embarrassed by how much time it took me to figure out this issue.